# сохранение изображения jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

здравствуйте, есть новостной блок .item , внутри него есть .news-img-area и внутри .news-img-area есть .def-newsimg с изображением внутри.

как можно при нажатии опр. кнопки которая находится в каждом новостном блоке, скачать изображение находящееся по адресу выше?

p.s. у каждого блока уникальное изображение

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я Вас правильно понял - попытался воспроизвести.

```js
var parent = document.querySelector(".news");
parent.addEventListener("click", showImg);

function showImg(e) {
  if (e.target.className === "news-button") {
    var img = e.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.childNodes[1].childNodes[1];
    document.location.href = img.src;
    /*
    // можно сделать открытие во всплывающем окне под размер картинки
                   var image = new Image();
                   image.src = img.src;
                   window.open(img.src, "Image", "width=" + image.width + ",height=" + image.height);
                   */
  }
}
```

```css
.news {
  width: 400px;
}
.item {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.def-newsimg {
  width: 100px;
}
.def-newsimg > img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.news-text-area {} .news-button {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="news">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="news-img-area">
        <div class="def-newsimg">
          <img src="http://icon-icons.com/icons2/108/PNG/256/males_male_avatar_man_people_faces_18373.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news-button">Скачать картинку</div>
      <div class="news-text-area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="news-img-area">
        <div class="def-newsimg">
          <img src="http://icon-icons.com/icons2/108/PNG/256/males_male_avatar_man_people_faces_18367.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news-button">Скачать картинку</div>
      <div class="news-text-area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="news-img-area">
        <div class="def-newsimg">
          <img src="http://icon-icons.com/icons2/108/PNG/256/females_female_avatar_woman_people_faces_18409.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="news-button">Скачать картинку</div>
      <div class="news-text-area">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```